# App crashes instantly after successful build

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build a app with Google API and i followed every steps that was given on internet to how to work with Google API, but when i run my app it launch and then closes instantly.

**Logcat**

```
04-21 19:07:19.857 16778-16778/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-21 19:07:19.858 16778-16778/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
04-21 19:07:20.052 16778-16778/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/lib/arm64
04-21 19:07:20.065 16778-16778/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-21 19:07:20.074 16778-16778/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kakarot.cpecroute, PID: 16778
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kakarot.cpecroute/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.kakarot.cpecroute.MapsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2698)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6605)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:999)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:889)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.kakarot.cpecroute.MapsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.kakarot.cpecroute-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2688)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6605) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:999) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
04-21 19:07:20.083 16778-16778/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16778 SIG: 9
```

.............................................................................

**AndroidManifest.xml/activity**

@Sagar  Yes, there is a activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
 Below is code

```
<activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 
         android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Comment: Is your `MapsActivity` listed in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Try perform a clean build or disable instant run temporary

Comment: I tried a clean build and then rebuild also disable instant run but nothing new happened.@KittoKatto

Comment: @Sagar  Yes, there is a activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
I will add the activity code of AndriodManifest.xml in above question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<activity android:name="com.yourpackagename.MapsActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

*Let me know is this works or not*

Comment: NO it did not work, app still crashes right after it launch it activity

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by upgrading my Gradle plugin version to `7.1.1`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
```